# Fedora 29 qemu time problem

Tags: fedora, virtual-machine, qemu

Since i upgraded my workstation from fedora28 to fedora29 i encountered a problem with my virtual machine which is running on my workstation. I am using this virtual machine for browsing in the internet.

My problem is that it seems like the time is running faster on the virtual machine than on my workstation. For example spotify or some videos are faster than normal.

Here is how i start this machine:

```
/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -cpu host -smp cpus=4 -hda /space/vm/images/browser.img -hdb /space/data/$USER/.browser_home.img -machine accel=kvm -daemonize -balloon none -vnc 127.0.0.1:0 -device intel-hda,id=sound0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x4 -device hda-duplex,id=sound0-codec0,bus=sound0.0,cad=0 -device ich9-usb-ehci1,id=usb,bus=pci.0,addr=0x6.0x7 -device ich9-usb-uhci1,masterbus=usb.0,firstport=0,bus=pci.0,multifunction=on,addr=0x6 -device ich9-usb-uhci2,masterbus=usb.0,firstport=2,bus=pci.0,addr=0x6.0x1 -device ich9-usb-uhci3,masterbus=usb.0,firstport=4,bus=pci.0,addr=0x6.0x2 -k de -m 2500 -net nic,model=virtio -net user,hostfwd=tcp:127.0.0.1:2233-:22 -monitor telnet:127.0.0.1:4444,server,nowait
```

I have no idea how to start debugging this one. What should i try?

Comment: Do you have any actual evidence that this is the case, such as comparing the output of `date` on the host and guest? How is time keeping done on the guest?

Comment: date seems similar, i guess the virtual guest should get his time from my host. And i think `date` confirms that but even if i configure ntp it is faster. @Kusalananda

Comment: It is "similar" and "faster" at the same time? You mean the video runs faster? In that case it's probably not a time problem but an issue with the speed of the video playback.

Comment: output of date seems to be similar, yes. But if i open spotify, youtube and so on, the time definately runs faster. not much, but it runs faster. And it definately has to do with fedora29.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is the virtual soundcard. Thats how i manage to get the sound from the VM to my host. But it seems like the soundcard calculates the wrong status.

`-device intel-hda,id=sound0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x4 -device hda-duplex,id=sound0-codec0,bus=sound0.0,cad=0`

The working way is to replace the settings with this.

`-soundhw es1370`